# Blazor Images in IndexedDB: RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds

Tags: .net, blazor, indexeddb

I am using Steve Sanderson's [InputFile](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile/) in Blazor web assembly to select photos to save as byte arrays in IndexedDB before uploading them. It all works fine for really small files, but once I have two photos in the DB at 700KB each, I get this error message in the console, and the site errors out. I will need to store a lot of photos at camera-resolution - do I need to do this another way? i.e. not store them in the DB? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Open an issue on the steve's github repo

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but it looks pretty inactive on there at present, with a backlog of issues and no reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this issue in a netcore 3.2 Blazor app (fetching somewhere between 1 and 2 Mb of data killed the runtime). I updated the application to .NET 5.0 and the problem went away (it worked with 50Mb of data).

Comment: thanks, I have left it alone until .net 5 came out - when I get a chance I will try it again now that InputFile is built into the tooling